# Bluebird Errors With Rethinkdb and Async

Tags: asynchronous, bluebird, rethinkdb

I recently changed my database from `mongodb` to `rethinkdb`. Since I'm getting  some bluebird errors. So I guess I have to return my db queries differently.

`Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it`

## Code

It is hard to tell where the errors occur, thus I'm posting some examples of how my db queries are coded.

### initialisation

```
exports.initDBandTables = (callback)->
  db = self.getConfig().db

  throw err "No DB Defined" if !db?

  r.dbList().contains(db)
    .do((databaseExists) ->
      return r.branch(
        databaseExists,
        { created: 0 },
        r.dbCreate(db)
      )
    ).run ()->
      async.parallel
        session: (next)->
          self.ensureTable('sessions', null, next)
        serverlogs: (next)->
          self.ensureTable('serverlogs', null, next)
        users: (next)->
          self.ensureTable('users', null, next)
        (err)->
          return callback err if err?
          return callback()
```

### example get:

```
r.table('users').filter(newFilter).select(selector).limit(limit).sort({lastName:-1}).run (err, usersFound) ->
  return callback err if err?
  return callback null, usersFound
```

### example create

```
r.table('users').insert(user).run (err, updatedUser)->
  return callback err if err?
  updatedUser = updatedUser || null
  return callback null, updatedUser
```

## Questions:

1) Is there a way to increase the verbosity? It is hard to investigate, without line numbers/ file/ or on which operation the error occurs.

2) The 1st error is related to promises which return undefined, but I'm returning my callbacks everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not with my code but with a module I used. 
https://github.com/armenfilipetyan/express-session-rethinkdb/issues/8